# C# stop async inheritance

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm getting in touch with the whole async / await functionality in C# right now.

I think I know what it is good for. But I encountered places where I do not want the common inheritance of all the methods which call a library function of mine to need to be "async" aware.

Consider this (rough pseudo-code, not really representing the real thing, it's just about the context):

```
string JokeOfTheHour;

public string GiveJokeOfTheHour()
{
    if(HourIsOver)
    {
        jokeOfTheHour = thirdPartyLibrary.GetNewJoke().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    return jokeOfTheHour;
}
```

1. I have a web-back-end library function which is called up to a million times per hour (or even more).
2. Exactly one time of these million calls per hour, the logic within uses a third party library which just supports async calls for the methods I want to use from it.
3. I don't want the user of my library to even think that it would make any sense for them to asynchronously run any code when calling my library-function, because it would only generate unnessecary overhead for their code and runtime the absolute most of the time.

The reasons I would state here are:

1. Seperation of Concern. I know how I work, my user does not need to.
2. Context is everything. As a developer, having background-knowledge is the way for me to know which cases I need to consider when writing code, and which not. That enables me to ommit writing hundreds of lines of code for stuff that should never happen.

Now, I want to know what general rules there are to do this. But sadly, I can't find simple statements or rules browsing the web where anybody sais "In this, this and this situation, you can stop this "async" keyword bubbling up your method-calltree". I've just seen persons (some of them Microsoft MVP's) talking about that there absolutely are situations where this should be done, also stating that you should use .GetAwaiter().GetResult() as a best practice then, but they are never specific about the situations itself.

What I am looking for is a down-to-the-ground general rule in which I can say:

Even though I might call third party functions which are async, I do not execute async, and do not want to appear as such. I'm a bottom level function using caches 99.99999% of the time. I don't need my user to implement the async methodology all the way up to where my actual user needs to decide where the async execution stops (Which makes my user who should actually benefit timely from my library do write more code and have more execution time).

I would really be thankful for your help :)

Comment: No, please read again. I'm not working async 99.99999% of the time. Also, synchronous calls and async calls are always mixed, if you consider any other operation which can't be done async being synchronous.

Comment: "Seperation of Concern." - Then why not take it to the max and separate getter and (async) updater?

Comment: Thank's for this idea. It's a really good one.

Comment: I support @Fildor's suggestion. And I also want to mention that with your current structure GetNewJoke will be called more than once if you are not using a locking mechanism. And using lock creates a big bottleneck in your case. So that is another reason for going with Fildor's suggestion.

Comment: As a library author, you **really** shouldn't try to hide async. The general advice is to neither write async wrappers for truly sync code nor sync wrappers for async code. You end up tying your consumers hands behind their backs.

Comment: Pair of articles by Stephen Toub - [part 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) and [part 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want your method to introduce itself with: "I'm fast". The truth is that from time to time it can actually be (very) slow. This potentially has serious consequences.

The statement

> I'm a bottom level function using caches 99.99999% of the time'

is not correct if you call your method once an hour.

It is better for consumers of your method to see "I can be slow, but if you call me often, I cache the result, so I will return fast" (which would be `GiveJokeOfTheHourAsync()` with a comment.)

If you want your method to always be fast I would suggest one of these options:

- Have an `UpdateJokeAsync` method that you call without waiting for it in your `if(HourIsOver)`. This would mean returning stale result until you fetch a new one.
- Update your joke using a timer.
- Make 'get' always get the last known and have `UpdateJokeAsync` to update the joke.